# Unable to display JavaScript popup

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to display a popup using JavaScript, however, the div with class="popup" is the only thing that is currently being displayed.  Both popup and popup2 should be displayed when the user performs an action.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="popup">
  <span class="popuptext" id="popup"></span>
</div>

<div class="popup2">
    <div class="popup2text" id="popup2"></div>
    <script src="/popup2.js"></script>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(() => {
  $('#enter').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      const newTask = $(this).val();
      if (newTask) {
```

*The above section of the javascript can be ignored*

```
        var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
        popup.classList.toggle("show");
        var popup2 = document.getElementById("popup2");
        popup2.classList.toggle("show");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #131313;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.95;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 581px;
  top: 180px;
  margin-left: -80px;
}

.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.5s;
  animation: fadeIn 0.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;} 
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity:1 ;}
}

#popup2 {
  visibility: hidden;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#popup2 .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.5s;
  animation: fadeIn 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: `keypress` only triggers on alphanumeric keys so you need `keydown` there.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML code is invalid.

Change this

```
<div class="popup">
  <span class="popuptext" id="popup"></span>
</div>

<div class="popup2"></div>
    <div class="popup2text" id="popup2"></div>
    <script src="/popup2.js"></script>
</div>
```

to this

```
<div class="popup">
  <span class="popuptext" id="popup"></span>
</div>

<div class="popup2">
    <div class="popup2text" id="popup2"></div>
    <script src="/popup2.js"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: I did but popup2 still won't be displayed, do you have any advice?

Comment: `popup2` wont be displayed because there is no `.show` css rule for `popup2`, only `popup`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by no .show css rule for popup2, because I toggled the class "show" for popup2 and also used css to define what popup2 would look like when the class is toggled.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your css, As it shouldn't be ".popup .show" and "#popup2 .show", instead it should be **"#popup.show" and "#popup2.show"**. Then I saw you have given css for ".popup" and not for ".popup2", css for "#popup2" but not for "#popup", similarly you have given css for ".popuptext" and not for ".popup2text".

Also Can you please ellaborate exact behaviour you want on page. Before user enter anything and after user enter something.